# Nesting MULTISET/ROW/MULTISET/ROW with ad-hoc converters and JSON emulation results in ClassCastException

Tags: java, jooq

When performing a select which includes a subquery in multiselect, which itself performs a subquery in a multiset, I would expect the result to have the expected type.

Instead, the nested result appears to be left as an `ArrayList` and not serialized properly to the target type.

#### Steps to reproduce the problem

```java
record Tuple2(String t1, String t2) {}

var result = db.select(
    multiset(
        select(
            row(
                multiset(
                    select(
                        row("Hello", "World").mapping(Tuple2::new)
                    ).from(dual())
                ).convertFrom(r -> r.map(Record1::component1))
            ).mapping(r -> r)
        ).from(dual())
    ).convertFrom(r -> r.map(Record1::component1))
).from(dual())
.fetchOne(Record1::component1);

log.debug("The result: {}", result);
log.debug("The tuple: {}", result.get(0).get(0));
log.debug("The type of the result: {}", result.get(0).get(0).getClass());
```

The expected type of `result` is `List<List<Tuple2>>` but instead it appears to be `ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList>>` (I'm guessing the raw representation of the row type).

The output of this code is:

```
The result: [[[[Hello, World]]]]
The tuple: [[Hello, World]]
An unhandled error occurred
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class com.mycompany.mypackage.MyClass$1Tuple2 (java.util.ArrayList is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.mycompany.mypackage.MyClass$1Tuple2 is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

#### jOOQ Version

3.17.8

#### Database product and version

MySQL 8.0.28

#### Java Version

openjdk version "19.0.1" 2022-10-18

#### OS Version

*No response*

#### JDBC driver name and version (include name if unofficial driver)

mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that was fixed in jOOQ 3.18.0, 3.17.9, and 3.16.15: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14657

The bug only affected `JSON` emulations of the `MULTISET` operator, not `XML` emulations, though that doesn't help as a workaround for MySQL, which doesn't support SQL/XML.

As noted in the bug discussion, this particular problem can be worked around by omitting one of the `row()` operators:

```java
var result = db.select(
    multiset(
        select(
            // row( Unnecessary in this case
                multiset(
                    select(
                        row("Hello", "World").mapping(Tuple2::new)
                    ).from(dual())
                ).convertFrom(r -> r.map(Record1::component1))
            // ).mapping(r -> r)
        ).from(dual())
    ).convertFrom(r -> r.map(Record1::component1))
).from(dual())
.fetchOne(Record1::component1);
```

I realise that this is just a simplified reproducer, the real query being more complex, though perhaps this helps work around the problem also in the real query, until the fix is available.